# onScroll event called multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to load more content when the user scrolls the webpage. I tried using

1. onScroll event javascript which is getting called multiple times
2. jQuery .scroll() method which is also called multiple times.

How do I handle this? Is it a browser issue?

Note: I am calling `onScroll = "function()"` on body tag of HTML.

Comment: I am not sure what the issue is, but I answered to the best of my ability

Comment: You mean once you scroll the event is triggered multiple times? Or you keep scrolling?

Comment: i am scrolling just once but the event is called multiple times .I am using Android phone which has webkit engine and chrome browser is guess .

Comment: @Preethi on every little scroll the scroll is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load content while scrolling: http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/load-content-while-scrolling-with-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

On **every scroll** any scroll method would be called

So you should check when the user scrolls to the bottom, then load more content.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting a series of events as the window moves (similar to what happens on a resize event), then one trick is to set a timer for 1-2 seconds on the first scroll event, but not do anything yet.  If a subsequent scroll event comes in before the timer fires, you stop the previous timer and set a new one.  When the user stops scrolling for a brief time, the timer will fire and you can then process the scroll event.  If they scroll some more, the whole process will repeat.

jQuery pseudo-code example:

```
var scrollTimer = null;
$("#target").scroll(function(){
    if (scrollTimer) {
        clearTimeout(scrollTimer);  // clear previous timer
    }
    // set timer while we wait for a pause in scroll events
    scrollTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        scrollTimer = null;  // timer done here
        // do your dynamic loading here
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: I set the timeout to 250ms, works fine to prevent this issue when user scrolls page on their phones.